# Assimp isn't found by CMake

Tags: c++, bash, cmake, makefile, assimp

Before saying anything: Yes, I googled and searched for a long time before asking this here so 99% the solution of other similar questions doesn't work for me.

I have an opengl application that uses the following libraries:

- glfw
- imgui
- glad
- stb
- assimp
- glm
- filebrowser (an extension of imgui for dialog boxes)

all these libraries are in a folder called external each one in its dir.
Moreover, glfw, assimp, glm are git submodules of my repo so they're downloaded when i clone my repo with git clone --recursive mygitrepo.

You can have a better understanding of the structure of the project looking at my [git repo](https://github.com/francescoschembri/TesiReskinner).

My idea was to use the add_subdirectories to make them compile with their own CMakeLists and my main one looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21.3)

project(Reskinner)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)     
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} Main.cpp)

add_subdirectory(external/glfw)
add_subdirectory(external/assimp)
add_subdirectory(external/glad)
add_subdirectory(external/imgui)
add_subdirectory(external/stb)
add_subdirectory(external/glm)
add_subdirectory(external/FileBrowser)
add_subdirectory(src)

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC external/glfw/include
    PUBLIC external/assimp/include
    PUBLIC external/glm
    PUBLIC external
    PUBLIC src
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} glfw glad imgui stb glm Engine assimp FileBrowser)
```

The project was developed with visual studio on windows and I want to compile it on linux without using visualstudio. The cmake doesn't give me any errors but when i run the make command it gives me this error:

> #include <assimp/quaternion.h> there's no file or directory with this name.

like i didn't put the assimp include folder in the cmake (but i did).

Do you have any idea how to make it works? I want to make a bash script to install all the dependencies and tools needed like xorg-dev, build-essential, git, cmake, make etc. So if there's any simple fix using some bash commands it's ok for me.

Comment: The correct name of the header is **lowercase**: `assimp/quaternion.h`. The incorrect name `assimp/Quaternion.h` could work on Windows, because its filesystem is usually *case-insensitive*.

Comment: I didn't know that and i changed it but it still doesn't find #include <assimp/quaternion.h>

Comment: Build with `make VERBOSE=1`, that way you could examine exact command lines used for compilation. Check that failed command line contains `-I` flag for assimp.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to fix it. I just installed conan and used it to download and find assimp. So I removed assimp, glm, glfw and glad from 'external' folder and just added a conanfile.txt.

Here the conanfile.txt:

```
[requires]
assimp/5.2.2
glfw/3.3.7
glm/0.9.9.8
glad/0.1.35

[generators]
cmake_find_package
cmake_paths
```

my main CMakeLists.txt now it's as following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21.3)

project(Reskinner)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)     
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} Main.cpp)

include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan_paths.cmake)

#   Retrieve conan.cmake
if (NOT EXISTS "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan.cmake")
    message(STATUS "Downloading conan.cmake from https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan")
    file(DOWNLOAD "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/conan-io/cmake-conan/master/conan.cmake" "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan.cmake")
endif ()

include("${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan.cmake")

conan_cmake_run(CONANFILE "conanfile.txt" BASIC_SETUP UPDATE BUILD missing)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(glad REQUIRED)
find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED)
find_package(glm REQUIRED)
find_package(assimp REQUIRED)

add_subdirectory(external/stb)
add_subdirectory(external/imgui)
add_subdirectory(external/FileBrowser)
add_subdirectory(src)

file(MAKE_DIRECTORY
        "${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/Shaders")

function(install_file_to_bin file_name)
    file(INSTALL "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Shaders/${file_name}" DESTINATION "${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/Shaders")
endfunction()

install_file_to_bin(1.model_loading.fs)
install_file_to_bin(1.model_loading.vs)
install_file_to_bin(4.1.fshader.fs)
install_file_to_bin(4.1.vshader.vs)
install_file_to_bin(animated_model_loading.fs)
install_file_to_bin(animated_model_loading.gs)
install_file_to_bin(animated_model_loading.vs)
install_file_to_bin(bb.vs)
install_file_to_bin(bb.fs)
install_file_to_bin(default.frag)
install_file_to_bin(default.fs)
install_file_to_bin(default.geom)
install_file_to_bin(default.vert)
install_file_to_bin(default.vs)
install_file_to_bin(floor.fs)
install_file_to_bin(floor.vs)
install_file_to_bin(framebuffer.frag)
install_file_to_bin(framebuffer.vert)
install_file_to_bin(grey_model.fs)
install_file_to_bin(grey_model.vs)
install_file_to_bin(hover.fs)
install_file_to_bin(hover.vs)
install_file_to_bin(influence_of_single_bone.fs)
install_file_to_bin(influence_of_single_bone.vs)
install_file_to_bin(mouse_shader.fs)
install_file_to_bin(mouse_shader.vs)
install_file_to_bin(normal_visualizer.fs)
install_file_to_bin(normal_visualizer.gs)
install_file_to_bin(normal_visualizer.vs)
install_file_to_bin(no_lighting_shader.fs)
install_file_to_bin(no_lighting_shader.vs)
install_file_to_bin(num_bones_visualization.fs)
install_file_to_bin(num_bones_visualization.vs)
install_file_to_bin(screen_shader.fs)
install_file_to_bin(screen_shader.vs)
install_file_to_bin(selected.fs)
install_file_to_bin(selected.vs)
install_file_to_bin(smooth_lighting_shader.fs)
install_file_to_bin(smooth_lighting_shader.vs)
install_file_to_bin(wireframe.vs)
install_file_to_bin(wireframe.fs)

set(CMAKE_CXX_INCLUDE_WHAT_YOU_USE 1)
set(CMAKE_LINK_WHAT_YOU_USE 1)
set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION TRUE)

include_directories(
    ${OpenGL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${glad_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${glfw3_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${glm_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${assimp_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    external
    src
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} 
    ${OpenGL_LIBRARIES} 
    ${glad_LIBRARIES}
    ${glfw3_LIBRARIES} 
    ${glm_LIBRARIES} 
    stb
    ${assimp_LIBRARIES}
    imgui
    FileBrowser
    Engine 
)
```

Some notes that can be usefull for other people having this troubles:

- Assimp has some linking problem when used with conan because it seems that it doesn't download everything but just what you need so it works for the #include but it complains in the linking phase. Adding the following 3 rows fixed the problem:

  set(CMAKE_CXX_INCLUDE_WHAT_YOU_USE 1)
  set(CMAKE_LINK_WHAT_YOU_USE 1)
  set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION TRUE)
- I have a script to install everything you need on linux and install the stuff with conan, launch the cmake etc.. Even if I install the conan packages with the command ***conan install .. [...]*** I need the conan.cmake file so the lines at the beginning looking for the conan.cmake files fixed a lot of problems

The shell scripts is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
sudo apt-get install xorg-dev
sudo apt-get install make
sudo apt-get install cmake
sudo apt-get install build-essential
cd build
rm -rf *
conan install .. --settings os="Linux" --settings compiler="gcc" --settings compiler.version=11 --build missing
cmake -S .. -B . -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
make
cd build
```

Hope this can help you